# Vuefire (Firestore) Very, Very Slow Queries

Tags: javascript, firebase, vue.js, google-cloud-firestore, vuefire

**UPDATE: TL;DR - NOT a firebase / vuefire problem**

In case anyone comes across this seeking a solution to speed issues - Neither firebase nor vuefire were at fault.

After much experimenting, I found that a fontawesome icon was the culprit - I have not figured out exactly how or why, but, in any event, this was NOT a firebase / vuefire issue.

---

I am using [Vuefire](https://vuefire.vuejs.org/) with a Firestore database.

Queries to the Firestore database for anything more than about 100 records are very slow.  For instance, a query that returns 700 records takes about 1 minute:

[image]

This is true on the first query and any subsequent query.

These are not large documents.

What am I doing wrong here?  Other than limiting the number of records returned to < 100 is there anything I can do to improve performance?

Relevant code (Vue CLI):

```
<script>

import { fb, db } from "@/firebaseConfig";

export default {
  name: "rules",
  data() {
    return {
      rules: []     
    };
  },

  firestore() {
    return {
      rules: db.collection("rules")
    };
  }
}

...

</script>
```

Comment: The retrieval of data from Firestore is typically fairly linear to the amount of data retrieved. How much data are you reading? How fast is the internet connection you retrieve it over? If this doesn't help you solve the problem yourself, can you set up a reproduction of the problem on a site like jsbin or stackblitz?

Comment: Per the screenshot in my question, just over 700 records totaling 57.2 KB.  Limiting the query to 200 records reduces query time to approx. 500ms.  Limiting the query to 100 records does not really reduce the query time to less than 500ms.

In any event 1 minute to retrieve 700 records is too long.

Comment: I am on fibre and my download speeds are very fast (for New Zealand...)

Comment: Hmm... not sure what's going on. Can you set up a reproduction of the problem on a site like jsbin or stackblitz, so we can have a look?

Comment: I've tried to set this up on stackblitz, but it does not load the vuefire plugin

Comment: I doubt VueFire impacts the performance much, so you might want to try reproducing without it. Also see [how to create a minimal, complete, verifiable example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).

Comment: Actually, I think it is something to do with VueFire - or vue.  When I simply .get() the data from Firebase and print to the console, it only takes about 2 seconds (as opposed to over a minute).  I can recreate this in stackblitz, too.

Comment: this method takes <2 seonds to download.  The equivalent vuefire code (commented out) takes over a minute.  Any clues?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/199219/discussion-between-alex-webster-and-frank-van-puffelen).

Answer (score 1):

**UPDATE:  TL;DR - NOT a firebase / vuefire problem**

In case anyone comes across this seeking a solution to speed issues - Neither firebase nor vuefire were at fault.

After much experimenting, I found that a fontawesome icon was the culprit - I have not figured out exactly how or why, but, in any event, this was NOT a firebase / vuefire issue.

Comment: Good to hear that you found the cause of the problem Alex!